# Is it possible to reduce this nginx proxy configuration?

Tags: nginx, upload, configuration

I'm having an hard time trying to find out how to reduce this "repeated lines" for my NGinx configuration, just to change one property :

```
server {
        #listen   [::]:443 ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
        listen    443;

        server_name my.website.com;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/my.website.com_access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/my.website.com_error.log;

        ssl  on;
        ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/website.com/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/website.com/cert.key;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP:!kEDH;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

        location / {
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:9010;

                client_max_body_size 1m; # I limit all the file upload to 1 Mo
                error_page         413 =200 https://my.website.com/errors/413; # I send back a 200 HTTP STATUS because Chrome crashes with a 413 (lol)

                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   Host               $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Ssl    on;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        # Now, for the two next locations, I will change the body size to 10Mo
        location = /picture/create {
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:9010;

                client_max_body_size 10m; # Here,
                error_page         413 =200 https://my.website.com/errors/413;

                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   Host               $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Ssl    on;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location ^/picture/([0-9]+)/edit$ {
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:9010;

                client_max_body_size 10m; # And here
                error_page         413 =200 https://my.website.com/errors/413;

                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   Host               $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Ssl    on;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to :

- Reduce the last two "Location" in one (listing the possible location ?)
- Avoid indicating 3 times the proxy_* configuration. I tried to put it on the server{} level, but it doesn't work (for obvious reasons). I also tried to not mention them on the last two location, but this results in a "Page Not Found" when I hit the url.
- (By the way, is my ssl_ciphers correct?)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do it is create a file and 'include' it. For example, create a new file called 'standard_include.conf', with the following text in it.

```
                proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:9010;    
                error_page         413 =200 https://my.website.com/errors/413;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   Host               $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Ssl    on;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Then have your standard config as:

```
#listen   [::]:443 ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
        listen    443;

        server_name my.website.com;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/my.website.com_access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/my.website.com_error.log;

        ssl  on;
        ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/website.com/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/website.com/cert.key;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP:!kEDH;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

        location / {
                include standard_include.conf;
                client_max_body_size 1m; # I limit all the file upload to 1 Mo

        }

        # Now, for the two next locations, I will change the body size to 10Mo
        location = /picture/create {
                include standard_include.conf;
                client_max_body_size 10m; # Here,               
        }

        location ^/picture/([0-9]+)/edit$ {    
                include standard_include.conf;
                client_max_body_size 10m; # And here
        }
```